# Problem with procedural eyes in blender 2.8

Tags: mesh, materials, node-editor, shaders, eevee-render-engine

Ok so i'm having a little bit of a problem with procedural eyes

here you can see them normally

[image]

but notice that one eye has more red than the other eye

so i tried do fix by separating the meshes

[image]

and i got this

so then i wanted to fix the other that has more red but when i separated the eyes into a single object

[image]

now they have the same red

so i was a little confused so i joined the eyes again but they reverted back to the one eye that has more red than the other

How can i fix this ?

All answers are welcome

Umm this is the video i watched for the eyes if anyone want to know

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0JyyWeptSA

oh i'm using eevee for rendering almost forgot

Comment: Do the two objects have the same material applied to them?

Comment: The easiest way would be to share your blendfile here. Without that, it’s just blind guessing. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/